# Dequeue Script Using Functions.php

Tags: functions

Hello I am trying to dequeue the script "jquery.favorite.js" found in my enqueue.php:

```
// WP_ENQUEUE_SCRIPTS
static function wp_enqueue_scripts_callback()
{
    global $javo_tso;

    $javo_register_scripts = Array(
        'oms.min.js'                                    => 'oms-same-position-script'
        , 'common.js'                                   => 'javo-common-script'
        , 'chosen.jquery.min.js'                        => 'jQuery-chosen-autocomplete'
        , 'jquery.javo.msg.js'                          => 'javoThemes-Message-Plugin'
        , 'jquery.parallax.min.js'                      => 'jQuery-Parallax'
        , 'jquery.favorite.js'                          => 'jQuery-javo-Favorites'
        , 'jquery_javo_search.js'                       => 'jQuery-javo-search'
        , 'jquery.flexslider-min.js'                    => 'jQuery-flex-Slider'
        , 'google.map.infobubble.js'                    => 'Google-Map-Info-Bubble'
        , 'pace.min.js'                                 => 'Pace-Script'
        , 'single-reviews-modernizr.custom.79639.js'    => 'single-reviews-modernizr.custom'
        , 'jquery.magnific-popup.js'                    => 'jquery-magnific-popup'
        , 'jquery.easing.min.js'                        => 'jQuery-Easing'
        , 'jquery.form.js'                              => 'jQuery-Ajax-form'
        , 'sns-link.js'                                 => 'sns-link'
        , 'jquery.raty.min.js'                          => 'jQuery-Rating'
        , 'jquery.spectrum.js'                          => 'jQuery-Spectrum'
        , 'jquery.parallax.min.js'                      => 'jQuery-parallax'
        , 'jquery.javo.mail.js'                         => 'jQuery-javo-Emailer'
        , 'bootstrap.hover.dropmenu.min.js'             => 'bootstrap-hover-dropdown'
        , '../bootstrap/bootstrap-select.js'            => 'bootstrap-select-script'
        , 'bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js'                  => 'bootstrap-tagsinput-min'
        , 'javo-footer.js'                              => 'javo-Footer-script'
        , 'bootstrap-markdown.js'                       => 'bootstrap-markdown'
        , 'bootstrap-markdown.fr.js'                    => 'bootstrap-markdown-fr'
        , 'jquery.quicksand.js'                         => 'jQuery-QuickSnad'
        , 'jquery.nouislider.min.js'                    => 'jQuery-nouiSlider'
        , 'okvideo.min.js'                              => 'okVideo-Plugin'
        , 'jquery.slight-submenu.min.js'                => 'slight-submenu.min-Plugin'
        , 'jquery.typehead.js'                          => 'jquery-type-header'
        , 'jasny-bootstrap.min.js'                      => 'jasny-bootstrap'
        , 'single-reviews-slider.js'                    => 'single-reviews-slider'
        , 'common-single-item.js'                       => 'common-single-item'
        , 'owl.carousel.min.js'                         => 'owl-carousel-script'
        , 'jquery.mixitup.min.js'                       => 'mixitup'
        , 'smoothscroll.js'                             => 'smoothscroll'
        , 'javo-single-property.js'                     => 'javo-single-property'

        /* Widget */
        , 'javo-wg-featured-scripts.js'                 => 'javo-wg-featured-scripts'
    );
```

I added this into my functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_remove_scripts');

function my_remove_scripts(){

    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery.favorite' );
    }
```

However it is still being called.

I could just delete from enqueue.php but I'd rather do this through functions.php.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove

```
, 'jquery.favorite.js' => 'jQuery-javo-Favorites'
```

from the `$javo_register_scripts Array`

OR

```
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jQuery-javo-Favorites' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but is there a way to do this through functions.php?

Comment: Just added that aswell

Comment: Its worth noting the late priority of `100` so that it is after the script was enqueued

Comment: To properly remove scripts or styles, you have to dequeue and deregister :-)

Comment: If your not going to use the script at all, then it would be better to NEVER enqueue it in the first place.

Comment: The `WP codex` doesn't mention anything about having to do both http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script If you want one completely removed then `wp_deregister_script` should suffice, otherwise `wp_dequeue_script` it http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

Comment: Note that things like `wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );` are useful if you want to register your own copy or from the `Google CDN`